# How to use information on another file to change what I have on the x-axis?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm sorry for the unclear title but I did not know how to better explain it.
I have the following problem: using pandas and seaborn, I want to graph some information that I have on my dataset. The dataset looks like this:

```
ParticpantID      ColorID
1                 3
2                 3
3                 4
4                 2
5                 1
6                 1
7                 3
8                 1
```

Now, I use:

```
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
    sns.countplot( x= "ColorID", data =dataset, palette = "magma" )
    plt.title("Participants per Color")
    plt.show()
```

And I get the countplot. The problem is that I have another file that looks like this:

```
ColorID      Color
1            Blue
2            Green
3            Red
4            Yellow
```

Every time I run my program, I want to open this second file, process it and substitute on my countplot the numbers 1-2-3-4 with the correct name of the color.
I am not sure how to do it. I though about using the function xticks() but I'm not sure how to implement it.

I'm sorry for the basic question, but I'm a total beginner. Thank you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to update your dataset with the string you want to set, using your color dataset.

Reconstructing your datasets (mind the `set_index`):

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = pd.DataFrame([
    [1,3],
    [2,3],
    [3,4],
    [4,2],
    [5,1],
    [6,1],
    [7,3],
    [8,1],
    ],
    columns=['ParticpantID','ColorID']
).set_index('ParticpantID')

#               ColorID
# ParticpantID         
# 1                   3
# 2                   3
# 3                   4
# 4                   2
# 5                   1
# 6                   1
# 7                   3
# 8                   1

color_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [1, 'Blue'],
        [2, 'Green'],
        [3, 'Red'],
        [4, 'Yellow'],
    ],
    columns=['ColorID', 'Color'],
).set_index('ColorID')

#           Color
# ColorID        
# 1          Blue
# 2         Green
# 3           Red
# 4        Yellow
```

Using `color_df` to translate `'ColorID'` into color string in `dataset`:

```py
dataset['Color'] = dataset['ColorID'].transform(lambda color: color_df['Color'][color])
```

Printing your plot, replacing `'ColorID'` by `'Color'` (the new key for the color string) as x axis:

```py
sns.set_style('darkgrid')

sns.countplot(
    x="Color",
    data=dataset,
    palette="magma",
)
plt.title("Participants per Color")
plt.show()
```

[image]

The key operation to understand here is the `transform` method: it allows you to transform (with the help of the lambda function) one column into another one.

Comment: I think this would be a bit simpler if you used `.map` instead of `.transform`

Comment: @mcnew if you appreciated the answer, could you please validate it and/or upvote it?